# Launch home screen chooser

Tags: android, homescreen

I have defined my app as home screen but I have to change the home screen during my app execution. I know it is not possible to change the home screen, it is only possible to launch the home screen selector. How could I launch the home screen selector when I need to do it?

I'm using:

PackageManager pm = getPackageManager(); pm.clearPackagePreferredActivities("com.dm.prado");

I have two problems:

The selector is only showed when I press home button, I want to show it when I want.

The selector is never showed again when I Selecthome screen first time

Answer (score 0):

> The selector is only showed when i press home button, i want to show
>   it when i want.

You can use the following piece of code to trigger the home screen intent from where ever inside your application

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);
```

Check this link for [Home screen](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Home/index.html) app development.

> The selector is never showed again when i Select home screen first
>   time

If you have selected the

> Use by default for this action

checkbox then it will not show on next time unless you clear default from the application.

Comment: Thanks Vignesh, the problem is not to select again my app after selecting it as default home screen with the chekbox "use by default for this action". For this pourpouse i'm using clearPackagePreferredActivities(). The problem is when the user select the phone home screen as default using the chekbox, because i don't know how to show the selector again to select my app as home screen